# Google Sign In API consent form

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have an android app that is using google sign in to authenticate users to my app.

On my Google API console, I've set up my project and i can see the following warning:

[image: consent-screen-warning]

It asks me to configure my consent screen.

When i try to configure it, i land on the following fields:

[image: authorized domains]

I do not have any websites' url to input in the authorized domain since i only have an android app published on the play store. This field is mandatory to send for verification.

Can someone advise what to put in this field ?

Comment: Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately some of these links are required if you intend to verify your application.  Mainly the privacy policy link. Your going to have to put this page up on the internet somewhere so that users can see your policy rules.

You shouldn't need to authorize a domain unless this is a web application.
You may want to read though [Setting up OAuth 2.0](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#authorized-domains)

There are some other things you will need to supply like You need to specify your Android app's package name and SHA1 fingerprint.

Comment: My privacy policy page is on google sites (which is a free but limited resource). Where should i put the link on the form ? Should it be on authorized domains ?

Comment: You cant add google sites to authorized domains you dont own it.  have you tried putting it where it says privacy policy.

Comment: I've tried it and it's getting verified. I hope it works. Thank you